# Low quality resolution issue on second monitor using HDMI port - GeForce GT 730 w/ Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, display-resolution, nvidia-geforce

I am running identical Dell monitors (model: E2016HV).  My primary display is working fine using the VGA port at 1600x900/60hz.  The second display has poor resolution (fuzzy/blurry text) which is using the HDMI port.  I am using a GeForce GT 730 (current driver version: 375.39) and running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Yes I have set the resolution using NVIDIA X Server Settings.